# Describe Sylow subgroups of $D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I should describe Sylow subgroups of $D_4$.
$|D_4| = 8 = 2^3$, so $D_4$ has just 2-subgroup.
But I don't understand, how can i prove it formally.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. To my mind you can just use the Sylow Theorems. Are you asking about the proofs of those? Or are you asking how you can use the theorems to prove this fact?

Comment: @MattS, thank you, I ask how can I use Sylow theorems here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through the various parts of Sylow's theorems, one by one, and try to understand how they apply to $D_4$.

> Part 1: If $|G| = p^n m$, where $p$ is prime and $p$ does not divide $m$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^n$. (Any such subgroup of order $p^n$ is called a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.)

As you correctly pointed out, $ D_4$ has order $2^3$, so $p = 2$ is the only prime that divides the order of $D_4$. And $2^3$ is the *highest* power of $2$ that divides the order of $D_4$. Therefore, a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $D_4$ is a subgroup of order $2^3$. Well, does $D_4$ contain a Sylow $2$-subgroup? Yes it does: the **entire** group $D_4$ is (trivially) a subgroup of $D_4$ of order $2^3$. So Part 1 is satisfied.

> Part 2: All Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate subgroups.

Well, the entire group $D_4$ is actually the *only* Sylow $2$-subgroup of $D_4$. And any subgroup is trivially conjugate to itself.

> Part 3: Suppose $|G| = p^n m$, and let $n_p$ be the number of distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Then $n_p$ divides $m$ and $n_p \equiv 1 {\rm \ mod \ } p$.

In our example, we have $p = 2$, $n = 3$, $m = 1$ and $n_2 = 1$. And yes, $ 1$ divides $1$, and $ 1$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $2$. So everything works!

Comment: Some versions of the Sylow Theorems state that if $p$ is a prime, and $p^k\mid |G|$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$. If this is what is intended, then there is yet more to do....